# First-order logic formula

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

If I want to express in first-order logic that 'the element(s) in the set with the smallest radius has the value 0', would the following be right?

> ∀ e<sub>1</sub> ∈ S.   ∀ e<sub>2</sub> ∈ S.   Radius e<sub>1</sub> ≤ Radius e<sub>2</sub>   ⇒   Value e<sub>1</sub> = 0?

Are the variables correctly quantified?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify with parentheses, what you wrote is usually taken to mean:

```
\forall e1 \in S. (\forall e2 \in S. (Radius e1 <= Radius e2 --> Value e1 = 0))
```

This statement asserts that the value of every element is 0. Here's how: Pick an arbitrary `e1`, now pick `e2 = e1`, and we have: `Radius e1 <= Radius e1 --> Value e1 = 0`.  Since the antecedent (thing before the `-->`) is true, we have `Value e1 = 0`.  And since we made no assumptions about `e1`, we have `forall e \in S. Value e = 0`.

The problem is that your parentheses are off.

```
\forall e1 \in S. (\forall e2 \in S. Radius e1 <= Radius e2) --> Value e1 = 0
```

In order for the antecedent to be true now, `e1`'s radius has to be less than or equal to *every* (as opposed to any) other radius, which seems like what you intended.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I think you want an exists</strike>

\exists e_1 . (\forall e_2 radius(e_1) <= radius(e_2)) and (radius(e_1) = 0)

I'm not sure about the precedence in the formula, but now that I think I understand the question, maybe you want (where *M* is the minimality condition `radius(e_1) < radius(e_2)`)

**\forall e_1 . ((\forall e_2 . *M*) -> value e_1 = 0)**

I think your previous formula may be wrong for the following reason. Suppose you have elements with radii { 0, 1, 2 }, and values equal to radii. Then, you will have a case where 1 <= 2, but the value is not zero. If I'm interpreting your original formula correctly,

**\forall e_1 . \forall e_2 . P(e_1, e_2)**

Then this counterexample provides a case where P is false, therefore the entire formula fails (but the example should be true).

Comment: This is wrong because the problem statement says there may be multiple elements with the smallest radius and they should all have value 0.

Comment: ah, sorry, I didn't get the differentiation between value and radius. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you wrote is also true if there are no elements with the smallest radius. If this is desired, you are correct; if not, you need to add a clause to that effect:

```
(\forall e1 \in S. \forall e2 \in S. Radius e1 <= Radius e2 --> Value e1 = 0) \and (\exists e1 \in S. \forall e2 \in S. Radius e1 <= Radius e2)
```

Comment: This has the same problem as the original.  This statement asserts that the value of every element is 0.

Comment: Don't vote him down b/c you think he's making mistakes! Vote downs should be reserved for cases where answers are opinion b/s unrelated to the question i.m.h.o. Voted back up :)

Comment: Well y.h.o. differs from m.h.o.  I want to draw the attention of future readers to the correct answers.

Comment: I agree with luqui, actually :)